# Flutter Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe if adding to animated list

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, animation, widget

I am using a `AnimatedList` in my app. The problem is that when trying to insert an item I get this error:

> Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

Here is my List:

```
child: AnimatedList(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        key: listKey,
                        initialItemCount: month.memories.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                          return slideIt(
                            context,
                            month.memories[index],
                            index,
                            animation,
                            month,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

Right now the List is in `View 1` and the user `pushes` to `View 2` where he adds the data on that `View 2` I am calling a `Callback Function` inside `dispose` so I get notified if the view was popped. Here is the logic for that:

```
CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
                      duration: Duration(
                        milliseconds: 350,
                      ),
                      expand: true,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AddMemoryPage(
                        memoryWasAdded: (addedMemory) {
                          if (addedMemory != null) {
                            _addMemory(context, addedMemory);
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    );
```

and `addMemory` looks like this:

```
  _addMemory(BuildContext context, Memory memoryToAdd) {

month.memories.add(memoryToAdd);

AnimatedList.of(context).insertItem(
  month.memories.length - 1,
  duration: Duration(
    milliseconds: 500,
  ),
);
```

}

What am I doing wrong here? I also tried it with `listKey.currentState` but that also fails because. `currentState` is null. What is the way to go here?

Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing the `callback` and simply pass a value on popping the 2nd screen (`pop(context, data`) and then I can retrieve it like this:

```
onTapped: () {
                    CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
                      duration: Duration(
                        milliseconds: 350,
                      ),
                      expand: true,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AddMemoryPage(),
                    ).then(
                      (memory) {
                        if (memory is Memory) {
                          _addMemory(context, memory);
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  },
```